# CreateParams in the Compact Framework

Tags: c#, compact-framework

I'm using the .NET Compact Framework and would like to subclass a PictureBox control (in this case to remove the CS_DBLCLKS style from specific instances of the PictureBox control). The code below works on .NET standard, but not the Compact Framework:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace NoDblClick
{
    public partial class NoDblClickPicControl : PictureBox
    {
        private const int CS_DBLCLKS = 0x008;
        public NoDblClickPicControl()
        {
        }

        protected override CreateParams CreateParams
        {
            get
            {
                // No compile, missing directive or assembly directive
                CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
                cp.ClassStyle &= ~CS_DBLCLKS;
                return cp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How do I get this to work on the Compact Framework? Perhaps I can PInvoke the functionality (from coredll.dll say)?

Answer (score 2):

These styles are applied when the window class is created, and to my knowledge cannot be changed on the compact framework. Besides `CreateParams`, the full framework allows a window handle to be recreated, which also is not possible on the compact framework.

You could manually filter the messages sent to the control, and convert the double click message back to a mouse down message:

```
public partial class NoDblClickPicControl : PictureBox
{
    private const int WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK = 0x0203;
    private const int WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201;
    private const int GWL_WNDPROC = -4;

    [DllImport("coredll.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, IntPtr newWndProc);
    [DllImport("coredll.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr CallWindowProc(IntPtr lpPrevWndFunc, IntPtr hWnd, uint msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    private delegate IntPtr WndProcDelegate(IntPtr hWnd, uint msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    private IntPtr prevWndProc;
    private WndProcDelegate @delegate;

    protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnHandleCreated(e);
        @delegate = new WndProcDelegate(MyWndProc);
        prevWndProc = SetWindowLong(Handle, GWL_WNDPROC, Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(@delegate));
    }

    protected override void OnHandleDestroyed(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnHandleDestroyed(e);
        SetWindowLong(Handle, GWL_WNDPROC, prevWndProc);
    }

    private IntPtr MyWndProc(IntPtr hWnd, uint msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        if (msg == WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK)
        {
            msg = WM_LBUTTONDOWN;
        }

        return CallWindowProc(prevWndProc, hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
}
```

Comment: BTW, I tried to remove the CS_DBLCLCKS style using PInvoke and Get/SetWindowLong in the form's constructor...and the CS_DBLCLKS style wasn't set for the PictureBox window class! This strongly suggests you are correct and you just cannot change Window styles in the Compact Framework...pity. Hmm, if its true that you cannot modify the window class styles in the CF, perhaps simplest is just to route the Click and DoubleClick events through the same handler? I've tried this and it does work.

Comment: A managed solution would always be preferred over P/Invoking imo, it just depends on what exactly you're trying to achieve.

Comment: The issue with the PictureBox is that if you rapidly click the control (faster than the OS double-click time, that is), half the events generated will be Click and half will be DoubleClick events. If you handle only Click events, the control feels "sluggish" compared with another control that only fires Click events. It would be most elegant to get the control to just generate Click events. In Delphi I can do this with pic.ControlStyle := (pic.ControlStyle - [csDoubleClicks]); but it looks like its trickier in C#...and impossible in the CF.

Comment: Have you considered using the `MouseDown` or `MouseUp` events instead?

Comment: Or add a double-click handler and inside it call the "action" method you use from click twice.